# Ionic v2 Google Maps API Android Build Error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable options.compassEnabled(controls.getBoolean("compass"));

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to implement the Google Maps API using the Ionic docs [as seen here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/).

I'm using the code samples exactly as supplied, but I'm getting the following error:

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2.748 secs

Error: /path/to/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
/path/to/platforms/android/src/plugin/google/maps/GoogleMaps.java:479: error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
        options.compassEnabled(controls.getBoolean("compass"));
               ^
  class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details
```

Has anyone seen/resolved this issue?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue. While a lot of the suggestions I found revolved around installing missing repositories (you need Android Support Repository, Library, Play Services and Google Repository), I had all that in place. What was missing was that incorrect versioning is specified in project.properties when I used this command to add the plugin:

```
ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"
```

In project.properties, I changed this:

```
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.8.0
```

To this:

```
cordova.system.library.4=com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:+
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+
```

That resolved the build error.

Comment: Note that this also requires that you use an emulator that can run Google Play services version 10.0 or greater. For me this meant installing the Google APIs SDK (currently listed under Android 7.0, SDK 24 in my SDK manager) and using that as the base image for the emulator.

Comment: This is not solving my problem. plugin/google/maps/PluginUtil.java:135: error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
    Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
                                  ^
  class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found

Comment: Thanks this is saved me much time.

Comment: Yeah Works fine for me. Thanx @Larry Turtis

Comment: Please have my babies. Or I'll have yours. I'm easy.