# Ionic build Android fail Google Maps PluginUtil.java cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable

Tags: android, google-maps, ionic-framework

I'm getting an error on android build, not iOS. Everything look fine but when I make:

```
ionic build android
```

It returns this:

```
:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).

/XXX/platforms/android/src/plugin/google/maps/PluginUtil.java:135: error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable

    Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
                                  ^
  class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

:compileDebugJavaWithJavac 
FAILED



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> 
Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.



* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.


BUILD FAILED




Total time: 22.331 secs

Error: /XXX/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
/XXX/platforms/android/src/plugin/google/maps/PluginUtil.java:135: error: cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
    Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
                                  ^
  class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Here goes some information:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.14
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
ios-deploy version: 1.9.0 
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: macOS Sierra
Node Version: v7.2.1
Xcode version: Xcode 8.2.1 Build version 8C1002
```

And plugins installed:

```
com.googlemaps.ios 2.1.1 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.0.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.3 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.0 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.8.3 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 1.7.4 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.3.0 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-googlemaps 1.4.0 "phonegap-googlemaps-plugin"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 1.5.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 3.2.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.1.3 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.2.2 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.0.8 "OneSignal Push Notifications"
```

Comment: Have you found any solution to this problem?

Comment: Update to las android api

Comment: Are you referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030573/ionic-v2-google-maps-api-android-build-error-cannot-access-abstractsafeparcelab?rq=1 (BTW this worked in my case)

Comment: You can do that, but update with sdk manager to the last android api

Comment: Ok, does the approach mentioned in that question has any side effects?

Comment: Nop, that helps also. Whats your last android api installed?

Comment: I have android sdk 25.0.1

Comment: Thats ok. Did it work for you?

Comment: I already had 25.0.1, but despite of this it was throwing above error. I finally had to update project.properties.

Comment: You will need to do that if you make ionic build android