# Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugGoogleServices'. > No matching client found for package name 'org.apache.cordova'

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

On a ionic app, I am trying to make push notifications work through Firebase, with cordova-plugin-fcm.
When trying to build for android i have this error:

> Execution failed for task ':CordovaLib:processDebugGoogleServices'.
>   No matching client found for package name 'org.apache.cordova'

I have read many post of persons having the same error, I understand it  happens when the package_name in google-services.json doesn't match the one defined in config.xml. Having my package_name defined correctly i don't get why i a m getting this error, especially the second line:

> No matching client found for package name 'org.apache.cordova'

I'm not sure but I assume this line mean I'm trying to use firebase on an app with package name org.apache.cordova, am I right?

My google-services.json file:

```
{
  "project_info": {
    "project_number": "746945719967",
    "firebase_url": "https://pliiizz-ec46a.firebaseio.com",
    "project_id": "pliiizz-ec46a",
    "storage_bucket": "pliiizz-ec46a.appspot.com"
  },
  "client": [
    {
      "client_info": {
        "mobilesdk_app_id": "1:746945719967:android:e3bad7385b3674c5",
        "android_client_info": {
          "package_name": "com.pliizzbis.usts"
        }
      },
      "oauth_client": [
        {
          "client_id": "746945719967-9bp7aq8h6i1lsosc3c7dfgqu26plgufl.apps.googleusercontent.com",
          "client_type": 3
        }
      ],
      "api_key": [ {"current_key": "AIzaSyC5JT3zGpzj1i9eRMTnDkbOveqADYK-Fgw"} ],
      "services": {
        "analytics_service": {
          "status": 1
        },
        "appinvite_service": {
          "status": 1,
          "other_platform_oauth_client": []
        },
        "ads_service": {
          "status": 2
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "configuration_version": "1"
}
```

The first lines of the config.xml file where my package_name is defined:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.pliizzbis.usts" version="0.0.32" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0\
">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have two plugins of "Google" look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41030573/ionic-v2-google-maps-api-android-build-error-cannot-access-abstractsafeparcelab/41042556#41042556), i had a similar problem and this worked for me