# Android Build error IONIC2

Tags: ionic2

I am new to ionic2 when i add google map plugin the android build successful.
But i need geofencing in my app. So when i add geofence plugin it give me following error.

```
And build failed.


cannot access AbstractSafeParcelable
    Builder builder = LatLngBounds.builder();
                                  ^

  class file for com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.AbstractSafeParcelable not found

Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
1 error

:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
```

[Package.json:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihrJr.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ihrJr.png)

Comment: _when i add geofence plugin_.. how and which plugin? also can you add your package.json?

Comment: ionic plugin add --save cordova-plugin-geofence this one

Comment: i have added package.json plz help.

Comment: hmm .looks ok.. is this related? http://stackoverflow.com/a/41042556/4826457

Comment: but my google map is working fine .

Comment: but when i add geofence plugin it gives me build error

Comment: is google play services installed in sdk?

Comment: yes it is installed

Comment: can anyone help me out withi build error